# pandas.DataFrame.groupby leaving out columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains some values and I want to sum up those values according to the `date` column.

The DataFrame looks like the following:

[image]

and when I run `pandas.DataFrame.groupby(['date']).sum()` I get

[image]

As you can see, this isn't the result that I want because I want all of the columns summed up, not just `polarity` and `subjectivity`.

Does anybody know why it's only summing up these two, and how might I get the desired result?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you run `df.dypes` to see which type your other columns have? They are probably not `numeric` (int or float). Thats why they are not getting summed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `numeric` columns to be able to do calculation on them, in this case `sum`:

```
#Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-01-04', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-03', '2018-12-22', '2018-08-31'],
                   'replies_count':['46', '143', '64', '154', '50'],
                   'polarity':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

print(df)
         date replies_count  polarity
0  2019-01-04            46        10
1  2019-01-04           143        20
2  2019-01-03            64        30
3  2018-12-22           154        40
4  2018-08-31            50        50
```

Check types of columns

```
print(df.dtypes)

date             object
replies_count    object
polarity          int64
dtype: object
```

Apply `groupby` with `sum`

```
print(df.groupby('date').sum())

            polarity
date                
2018-08-31        50
2018-12-22        40
2019-01-03        30
2019-01-04        30
```

Now change type of `replies_count` column to `int` and do the same `groupby` with `sum`

```
df['replies_count'] = df['replies_count'].astype(int)

print(df.groupby('date').sum())
            replies_count  polarity
date                               
2018-08-31             50        50
2018-12-22            154        40
2019-01-03             64        30
2019-01-04            189        30
```

As we can see, the column is included now.